# Ordering user's messages SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to build a user's message inbox by grouping conversations by people the user has sent messages to.

So I want a list of users but i want the first user in the list to be the one who sent the most recent message.

My `message` table has the fields: `id, sender_id, receiver_id, text`

And the following query gives me the list i need but doesn't order them by in descending order of message id.

```
SELECT sender_id AS messgr_id FROM   messages WHERE  receiver_id = '$sess_id' 
UNION
SELECT receiver_id AS messgr_id FROM messages  WHERE  sender_id = '$sess_id'
```

I am hoping there is a way to order the results in SQL without having to use a potentially slower php process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `id` is an identity column (specifically you will want it to be [auto incrementing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)) then a larger id indicates that a record is more recent.  You will be able to sort by id in this case in descending order to get newer messages first.  Something like this (untested):

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN receiver_id = '$sess_id' THEN sender_id
            ELSE receiver_id END AS messgr_id
FROM messages
WHERE  receiver_id = '$sess_id'
OR sender_id = '$sess_id'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: When there's no date/time field, that is the only possible solution.

Comment: this does NOT work...the idea is to have a list of unique users this will give a list of unique messages...

Comment: Then what you can do is change `SELECT id` to `SELECT MAX(id)` and add a group by clause to `GROUP BY messgr_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Zeus says, why can't you have a datetime stamp for the messages?

A messaging system without datetime stamp is not a messaging system.

The datetime stamp is the *natural* means to sort your messages.

Comment: how does this help? a date time stamp belongs to each message...i am grouping users NOT messages...i.e. grouping a group of messages...an id field essentially keeps track of order in the same wya time does...